# When does IIS create an AppPool identity?

Tags: iis, application-pool

I've created an IIS administration tool designed to create new applications, assign them to a new AppPool, and add required folder ACLs for the identity associated with that AppPool. According to [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities), **Whenever a new Application Pool is created, the IIS management process creates a security identifier (SID) that represents the name of the Application Pool itself.**

But that doesn't appear to be the case on my Windows 8 Pro machine (IIS8). The SID is only being created once an application associated with the AppPool starts. This is making the task of setting folder ACLs quite difficult, the application needs to start before the AppPool identity is created, but the application won't work unless the ACLs are set... chicken and the egg.

What's going on here? Is there a bug on my Win8 machine? Is this Win8 / IIS8 behaviour in general? I'm having no issues on Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5), where it **does** create the AppPool identity SID as soon as the AppPool is created in IIS.

I'm aware there is an indeterminate *delay* between the time the AppPool is created and the SID is created. This is generally less than a second. In this instance, the delay appears indefinite (several minutes later, the SID still does not exist).

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm not experiencing this issue on a Windows Server 2012 Standard machine, with IIS 8. Both are the same version of IIS - 8.0.9200.16384. And both have the same application pool defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the SID is only created once the process is running. I have a related problem where the registry hive under HKEY_USERS completely disappears after a reboot. Tests indicate that the registry hive returns fully intact as soon as my web service starts (i.e. on first request) with the same SID and contents fully restored, so I guess that once you have obtained the SID for the first time you can use it for the same purposes even if it doesn't yet exist after a restart. Getting the security system to believe you havn't made a mistake with naming may still be an issue though.